# ColorLS icon does not show up

Tags: zsh

It is said `colorls` is able to list the contents of a directory and display icons beside folder and file names, and I've been following the installation [here](https://github.com/athityakumar/colorls/blob/master/README.md#installation).

I am using Hyper zsh, and what I did is:

First install nerd fonts

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-fonts
brew cask install font-hack-nerd-font
```

Then

```
gem install colorls
```

and lastly add

```
source $(dirname $(gem which colorls))/tab_complete.sh
```

in `~/.zshrc`

BUT in the end what showed in my `Hyper` shell is still some square boxes when I list the folder.

I guess there should be an extra step that links `Hyper` shell to use the font, but I don't know how to do that

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the `fontfamily` attribute in the `~/.hyper.js` file to use Nerd Font.
For instance, I added "MesloLGMDZ Nerd Font".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please describe your answer so easily understand by other person

Comment: hi, how could I know which nerd font did I install, I tried several different ones in my hyper.js, like `MesloLGMDZ Nerd Font, Hack Nerd Font, ...`, but none of them worked

Comment: If you are running macOS, fonts you installed are mostly likely to be inside `~/Library/Fonts`, also make sure you added double quotes to the font name.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your terminal font if you use OSX
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCrva.png)